# Boolean Algebra and negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

> $$
>   -(A \ast -B) \ast -(-A \ast B) 
> $$

My understanding is that the above logic is equal to
$$
  (-A \ast B) \ast (A \ast -B)  = 
  (-A \ast A) \ast (-B \ast B) = \mathrm{FALSE}
$$

but my textbook says that my first manipulation is wrong. According to what laws am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$$
  -(A \ast -B) \ast -(-A \ast B) 
$$
Using the rule $
  -(X \ast Y) = (-X + -Y) 
$, dont forget the and becomes an or and vice versa
$$
  = (-A + --B) \ast (--A + -B) 
$$
$$
  = (-A + B) \ast (A + -B) 
$$
Multiplying out gives
$$
  = -A \ast A + -A \ast -B + b \ast A + B \ast -B
$$

$$
  = FALSE + -A \ast -B + B \ast A + FALSE
$$
or just
$$
  = (-A \ast -B) + (A \ast B)
$$
ie XNOR

---

$$
  -(A \ast -B) \ast -(-A \ast B) 
$$
From here we could join the negation to give

$$
  -((A \ast -B) + (-A \ast B)) 
$$

which is the negation of XOR or XNOR from the start

Comment: so  -1(x+y) = -x -y is not true in Boolean algebra?

Comment: -1 would be 0 or false, so not quite, boolean algebra follows the same rules as algebra mostly, but negation is not like a minus sign

Comment: Why on earth do they use the minus sign for boolean algebra?! In most standard references one sees "$a+b$" and "$a \cdot b$" and "$a'$" for the mathematical versions "$a \lor b$" and "$a \land b$" and "$\neg a$" respectively.